# Real Time Processing - read a managed object fragment

Tags: cumulocity

I'd like to use the Event Processing functionality to create derived measurements.

Our devices report a measurement that has a target value we store, per-device, in a managed object fragment. I want to create a device measurement that is the difference between the measurement and the target, it seems an ideal candidate for RTP/CEL implementation.

I've looked at the [real time processing](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/concepts/realtime/) guide but can't quite work out how to read a fragment from a managed object.

Edit. I updated my code and I'm nearly there, I just can't work out how to use the incoming deviceId from the measurement as the place to get my fragment data from.

```
create variable ManagedObject device =  findManagedObjectById(m.measurement.source.value);
create variable BigDecimal setpoint = getNumber(device, "uty_Setpoint.value");

insert into CreateMeasurement
select
  m.measurement.time as time,
  m.measurement.source.value as source,
  "uty_Pressure_delta" as type,
   {"uty_Pressure_delta.T.value", getNumber(m, "uty_Pressure.pressure.value") - setpoint,
   "uty_Pressure_delta.T.unit", "percent"  } as fragments
from MeasurementCreated m
where getNumber(m, "uty_Pressure.pressure.value") is not null
```

Comment: You should do it directly in the statement not as a variable outside. So replace setpoint with getNumber(findManagedObjectById(m.measurement.source.value), "uty_Setpoint.value")
Edit: Background is that the variables like you declared them are resolved on deployment of the statement (which  won't work because m.measurement.source.value cannot be resolved)

Comment: That explains why it worked once each time I redeployed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to query the object based on the source of the  measurement

```
findManagedObjectById(measurement.source.value)
```

You can also take a look at the geofence example which also reads some parameter from the device object.

http://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/geofence/

Afterwards you can access the fragment with these functions:

```
getNumber(deviceObject, "myFragmentInDevice.value")

getString(deviceObject, "myFragmentInDevice.value")
```

I would ensure that the target value is stored as a number and not a string because then you can use the getNumber function which will return a BigDecimal.

http://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/functions/#utility-functions